# Hadoop / Spark: kill a task and do not retry

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I would like to know if there is a way to stop a job (and have it in a FAILED or KILLED state) when I detect something wrong within a map or a reduce task without Hadoop retries the task.

If possible I would like to keep the fact that on "normal" fails Yarn restart the task.

Currently I am throwing an exception but Hadoop tries again.

It is Scala/Spark code but It may be useful in Java/Hadoop too.

Thanks

Comment: `yarn application -kill <application_id>`?

Comment: I would prefer an api call from my code or something like a special exception

Comment: Well, you can stop the SparkContext if you are able to catch the exception, or calling `System.exit(0)` will forcibly terminate the task, but YARN / Spark will always continue to retry a specific number of times by default. I can't remember what the properties are to disable that

Comment: Throwing the exception is not enough. You can specify the nbr of retries of your Spark application with this setting: `spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1` (by default it's 2, which is annoying)

Comment: @XavierGuihot It is not a duplicate, he wants to run once and I want to retry on "normal" fails but fail and not retry on "my" fail.

Comment: Ok, I understand better; my bad.